# Split Array Value keep first element

Tags: json, windows, powershell, scripting

I'm trying to extract just the IPs from a filtered JSON using the following code:

```
$curl = Invoke-WebRequest -Method Get -Uri "http://urltojson.com/file.json"
$curl2 = $curl.Content.Replace("Script", "Script_").Replace("iphone", "iphone_").Replace("android", "android_").Replace("ipad","ipad_") |
         ConvertFrom-Json
$curl3 = $curl2 | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "/Common/cloudfront_nets"} |
         Select-Object -ExpandProperty data
$curl3
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$curl3[0] = $curl3
$curl3[1]
```

Which returns the following

```
13.59.250.0 255.255.255.192    : region: us-east-2-service: CLOUDFRONT
52.57.254.0 255.255.255.0      : region: eu-central-1-service: CLOUDFRONT
54.182.0.0 255.255.0.0         : region: GLOBAL-service: CLOUDFRONT
52.212.248.0 255.255.255.192   : region: eu-west-1-service: CLOUDFRONT
205.251.250.0 255.255.254.0    : region: GLOBAL-service: CLOUDFRONT
35.162.63.192 255.255.255.192  : region: us-west-2-service: CLOUDFRONT
13.32.0.0 255.254.0.0          : region: GLOBAL-service: CLOUDFRONT
205.251.254.0 255.255.255.0    : region: GLOBAL-service: CLOUDFRONT
```

I'm struggling to simply output the IPs (without the subnet-mask).

Can anyone help please?

Comment: I would suspect that the structure `$curl3` is not what you think it is. What is the output of `$curl3 | Get-Member`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$myArray -split` to split your last `$curl3[1]` on the spaces and then just select the first array value.

For example `($curl3[1] -split " ")[0]` would give you just the IP address from that string.

Comment: thanks for your reply. That simply returns @{13.59.250.0